# WD mybook 6tb randomly disconecting

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, external-hard-drive, mybook

I have multiple hard drives hooked up to my computer (2tb WD portable, 2tb segate portable, 4tb Toshiba 2 tb Toshiba and two 6tb WD mybooks ).

The two Mybooks will randomly disconnect at anytime when their idle or when im using them. 
I have disabled auto off in both the power settings and the wd tools.

it only seems to happen when i have them hooked up to my desktop (running windows 10) they work perfectly fine on my laptop (running Kodibuntu)

[My Computer](http://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04708726)

Comment: Your link does not work.

Comment: The links working fine for me, here's the name of my computer through:       HP Pavilion 550-019.

Comment: It's a 404.....the link does not work, this isn't an ISP problem on my end

Comment: @Ramhound The link works here. You are broken :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a power issue, a bad USB connector, related to the external HDD sleep on idle or some other issue.

1. To check if sleep-on-idle is the issue, try an application such as [NoSleepHD](http://nosleephd.codeplex.com/) or [KeepAliveHD](http://keepalivehd.codeplex.com/), or the WD utility that sets idle sleep time. BTW, Ubuntu keeps my external drives from idling.
2. To check the USB port, try using just one drive, and use a different port from the one you use, or use a *powered* external USB adapter, e.g. [this USB 3.0 4-port adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DQFGH80) .